# Как можно обезопасить токены сохраненные на устройстве?

Tags: android, token, oauth2

Есть задача: нужно безопасно сохранить токен доступа и рефреш токен, но нельзя использовать Account Manager. KeyChain тоже не подходит, т.к. приложение будет для API 10+ На ум приходит шифрование sharedpreferences или бд, но тут возникает ситуация когда нам нужен пароль для шифрования, а его по условию задачи нельзя хранить на устройстве и шифровать пользовательским паролем тоже.

Есть ли у Вас мысли на этот счет?)
Заранее спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

Решение, когда пароль шифрования генерируется на лету на базе уникально идентификатора устройства + соль + ПИН пользователя, считается достаточно надежным даже для банковских мобильных приложений.

Вместо пользовательского ПИН можно использовать RFID/NFC метку на выбор пользователя, любимый QR-код и т.п. Но тут встает вопрос о уровне подготовки  пользователя.

Исключив пользователя, вы исключаете важное звено в генерации случайного пароля, которое довольно сложно заменить каким-либо техническим решением.